# NameError: name 'webexample' is not defined

Tags: python, django

Here's the code in `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from webexample import views
from django.conf.urls import url, includes
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('webexample/', include(webexample.views.index)),
]
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ccc\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 23
path('webexampsle/', include(webexample.views.index)),
NameError: name 'webexample' is not defined
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: you have 1 `[` but 2 `]`, you have 3 `(` but only 2 `)`.

Comment: Please don't change the question entirely after someone has already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot an the second closing bracket `)`:

```
path('webexample/', include(webexample.views.index)), # <-- here
```

Note: this is the answer to the OP's original question before the edit

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have imported `views`, so you should use `views.index` instead of `webexample.views.index`. Secondly, the `index` view is a single view, so you should not use `include()`.

```
path('webexample/', views.index),
```

The `include()` function is used to include another urls.py, for example:

```
path('webexample/', include('webexample.urls')),
```